# der_encode() fails to encode ASN1 message

Tags: c, decode, encode, asn.1

I am using open source ASN1 compiler at https://github.com/vlm/asn1 and I am having a problem when trying to encode my message.

I have the following `TCIMsg_t` type:

```
typedef struct TCIMsg {
    long     version;
    Time64_t     time;
    Frame_t  frame;
    /*
     * This type is extensible,
     * possible extensions are below.
     */
    
    /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
    asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
} TCIMsg_t;
```

When I try encoding with der_encode() function as below,

```
        TCIMsg_t* tci_msg = (TCIMsg_t *)calloc(1, sizeof(TCIMsg_t));
        const char *filename = av[1];
        FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "wb");

        if(!fp){
            perror("filename");
            exit(1);
        }

        ec = der_encode(&asn_DEF_TCIMsg, tci_msg, write_out, fp);
        // ec = oer_encode_to_buffer(&asn_DEF_TCIMsg, 0, tci_msg, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        fclose(fp);
        if(ec.encoded == -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not encode TCIMsg (at %s)\n",
            ec.failed_type ? ec.failed_type -> name:"unknown");
            exit(1);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Created %s with BER encoded Event\n", filename);
        }
```

it fails to encode and I get the `Could not encode TCIMsg (at Frame)` message. `Frame` is just another nested struct like below

```
typedef struct Frame {
    Frame_PR present;
    union Frame_u {
        TCI16093_t   d16093;
        TCI80211_t   d80211;
        TCI16094_t   d16094;
        TCI29451_t   d29451;
        TCISutControl_t  sutCtrl;
        /*
         * This type is extensible,
         * possible extensions are below.
         */
    } choice;
    
    /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
    asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
} Frame_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample is (if complete), not actually populating the allocated tci_msg or included Frame. I don't know what's in the schema file that's defined TCIMsg or Frame, but probably:

1. You'll need to at least set the value of tci_msg->frame.present (which I'm guessing is the field that says what member of the Frame_u is filled). It feels like Frame is defined as containing a CHOICE, and the encoder needs to know how the CHOICE has been populated (something not in your code sample).
2. If there's any constraints anywhere in the .asn schema file, and the uninitialised tci_msg isn't complying with those constraints, then the encoder would rightly return an error.

A lot more could be learned from seeing the content of your .asn schema file!